# Receive data from firebase nested collections

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using firebase + Angular.

I need to access data from a collection (orcamentosRecebidos) that is within another collection (Projects), the collection (orcamentosRecebidos) contains several documents. I need to loop through all documents within (Projects), access the sub-collection (orcamentosRecebidos) within each project, and loop through all documents contained in the collection again, making a comparison, comparing the "id" contained within of each document with the id of the logged in user (which in this case is in the storage in the browser).
I need this query to return all documents in which the "id" of the collection is equal to the user's id (the "id" property is within each document! I'm not talking about the document's id).

Here are some images from firestore to better illustrate.

[image]

First access the "Projects" collection, then loop through all the documents and access the "orcamentosRecebidos" collection for each of the documents.

[image]

After that, make a new loop through each of the documents within the "orcamentosRecebidos" collection and return the documents that have the "id" property equal to the "id" of the logged in user.

my firebase imports:
import { Firestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { collection, query, where, getDocs, doc, getDoc } from 'firebase/firestore';

I use the Angular/Fire library for some queries.

I tried this query with several different scripts, all without success, I think I'm missing something along the way...

```
  async pegarOrcamentosDoUsuario() {
    const q = query(collection(this.firestore, "projects/orcamentosRecebidos"), where("id", '==', localStorage.getItem('app_auth')));
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      console.log("id doc:", doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
    })
  }
```

Can someone help me??

Answer (score 0):

You're querying `collection(this.firestore, "projects/orcamentosRecebidos")`, but no such path exists in your database screenshots.

You'll need to specify the full path to the collection you want to query (so `collection(this.firestore, "projects/p2GmsCMmHUImtUGJHuf/orcamentosRecebidos")`), or alternatively you can use a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) to query all `orcamentosRecebidos` collections.

Comment: I tried that way too and nothing came back.
And I need to loop through all projects, not just (p2GmsCMmHUImtUGJH6uf), is there any alternative for this?
Do a loop through all the projects, and after accessing the collection (orcamentosRecebidos), do a new loop through all the documents, to, yes, compare the "ids"?

Comment: If you want to query across all `orcamentosRecebidos`, you can use a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query). If that doesn't work, edit your question to show what you tried.

Comment: Please don't post additional information about your question in an **Answer**, as it'll get deleted for not being an actual answer. Rather, edit your question to make sure it has the information we need to help you troubleshoot. --- Trying to `.where` on a `Query` doesn't work in the API that you use. Use the sync for `where` as [this doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#web-modular-api_17), which is the same as you have in your original code.